# Extract list from a list

Tags: nested, nested-for-loop

`students = [["BSIT",["JOSHUA", "CRISA", "JAYMARK"]], ["BSCS",["BOBS", "CARLO", "GERALD"]]]`

how can I extract items from the list and print them individually using nested for loop; the result must be

BSIT
-JOSHUA
-CRISA
-JAYMARK

BSCS
-BOBS
-CARLO
-GERALD

Comment: Hi Sian! Could you add a bit more detail please? Like which language you are working with? Different languages may handle this differently. Do you want the print out to be on separate lines as shown or just separated by dashes (BSIT-JOSHUA-..)?

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```py
for cat, person_list in students:
    print(cat)
    for person in person_list:
        print(‘-‘, person)
```